# local.xml & theme updates

Tags: theme, local.xml, theme-fallback

I'm trying my best to understand more about the `local.xml` file.  If I may, could some kind soul answer a couple of questions I have?

1. As I understand it, Magento will only read one `local.xml` file when rendering the page?  I think this is true, because I just created a blank local.xml file in my child theme and the site was completely broken as a result.
2. I use the Ultimo theme and I can see in the file directory that it uses it's own local.xml file, located at: `app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/layout.`  If I was to modify this `local.xml` file, will the changes get overwritten when I update the theme?  Updates for Ultimo are common and presumably this file gets modified now and again by the developers?

Thanks for taking the time to read this.  `Magento is fascinating to use but also very complicated for us beginners.`

Comment: "very complicated for us beginners" - Understatement of the year. It took years of working with Magento before I finally started feeling "Oh, I get it. Okay, I just do this..."

Answer (score 3):

Magento is using theme fall back mechanism to locate a theme specific file (either layout update files or template files).

Suppose your package and theme are configured as below

[image: Theme-Fallback]

Now magento will look for `local.xml` file in the following order

```
Package/Theme                             Location
__________________________________________________________________________________________
mypackage/mytheme   app/design/frontend/mypackage/mytheme/layout/local.xml
                    [app/design/frontend/mypackage/mytheme/template/{path-to-a-template-file}
                    skin/frontend/mypackage/mytheme/{path-to-a-resourece}]

mypackage/default   app/design/frontend/mypackage/default/layout/local.xml
                    [app/design/frontend/mypackage/default/template/{path-to-a-template-file}
                    skin/frontend/mypackage/default/{path-to-a-resourece}]

base/default        app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml
                    [app/design/frontend/base/default/template/{path-to-a-template-file}
                    skin/frontend/base/default/{path-to-a-resourece}]
```

As you can see, magento will first look into `mypackage-mytheme` section first for `local.xml` file. If it finds one, then use it and fallback mechanism ceases. If it couldn't find `local.xml` file there, then it will look into `mypackage-default` section. If finds, then use that otherwise fallback mechanism continues to `base-default` section. This is the end location. If it cant find a file with name `local.xml`, then magento simply ignores it. However this fallback mechanism is used between `magento-1.4 -> magento-1.8`

***From `magento-1.9`, fallback mechanism slighly changed. It now uses `infinite fallback mechanism` which will give a chance to fallback into any number of theme levels.*** For more details, you can look into **[alanstorm article](http://alanstorm.com/magento_infinite_fallback_theme_xml)**

In short, from `magento-1.9`, theme fallback works like below. Let us assume you have 4 custom packages

```
package1/theme1
package1/theme2
package2/theme3
package3/theme4
```

Now suppose

> package3/theme4 is a child of package2/theme3 is a child of packag1/theme2 is a child of package1/theme1 is a child of rwd/default

** *Yes, from `magento-1.9` we can set a parent theme for another theme. This is done via
a special file called `theme.xml`*

Assume you are using `package3/theme4` in your application. Now magento look for `local.xml` like in the follwing order

```
package3/theme4    app/design/frontend/package3/theme4/layout/local.xml
package2/theme3    app/design/frontend/package2/theme3/layout/local.xml
package1/theme2    app/design/frontend/package2/theme2/layout/local.xml
package1/theme1    app/design/frontend/package1/theme1/layout/local.xml
rwd/default        app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/local.xml
```

This is known as `infinite fallback mechanism` since as the themes become depending on another theme, then fallback mechanism also grow up !!!

Hope that will give you a good idea.

Comment: This is a great answer!

Comment: @LiamMcArthur Great to hear that!!!

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that yes, only one local.xml will be read. But that doesn't mean that your child theme can't make changes. My suggestion is to carefully read [this great article](http://alanstorm.com/magento_infinite_fallback_theme_xml) by Alan Storm on theme inheritance. While it's not totally required that you install the module that is mentioned in the article, I've used it to great effect to have a child of a child of a child theme in a large Magento site.

Comment: Thanks for providing that link. I am enjoying all of your answers now. :-) +1 for this.